# How can I set lifecycle rule for object (minIO)?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, minio

I'm looking for solution that allow me to set lifecycle policy for object in minio storage.

***What do I want?***
I want to delete objects from `minIO` storage after 30 min.

***Possible, but not suitable solution***

1. Chronos + `mc rm -f --older-than 30m`.
2. AWS S3 Lifecycle rule (it doesn't allow to set lifecycle using minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [minio](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/9240)

The lifecycle checks every 24 hours. So the 30 mins expiration won't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
mc rm --recursive --dangerous --force --older-than 30m local
```

`"local"` should be described in the file  `~/.mc/config.json`

Comment: this option is better than setting lifecycles, becaus lifecycles dont run sometimes.